# How to check if key exists in array of bytes?

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping, bytes

I have an array of `bytes10` inside a mapping, like this:

```
mapping(uint => bytes10[]) public Players;
```

I want to check if a certain index exists in the `bytes10` array.
I tried to check it with `.length` but it throws `opcode` error when the index does not exist.

Comment: "I tried" - well how exactly did you try? And what does the `mapping` have to do with all of this? Doesn't sound related to your problem.

Comment: `Players[_id][i].length` results in same opcode error.

Comment: And what does `Players[_id].length` result with? (spoiler: 0 - does that answer your question)?

Comment: That was funny, but was wrong :) It returns 4.

Comment: And what value of `i` do you use in the expression `Players[_id][i].length`?

Comment: 0, 1, 2, 3 working fine, 4 throws error.

Comment: Do you know how array indexing works?

Comment: @goodvibration Thank you, let's see if anyone else can help.

Comment: HINT: You've got length = 4, and then you're trying to access 5 elements (at indexes 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4). What exactly do you expect to happen?

Comment: "anyone else" is going to tell you the exact same thing - you can access array of length `x` only at indexes between `0` and `x - 1`.

Comment: I want to check if an index exists or not. This is reasonable.

Comment: You want - that's reasonable. The way you are doing it - that's not reasonable (I mean, according to what Solidity allows you to do). If your length is 4, then you can access the elements at indexes 0, 1, 2 and 3. If you access anything higher than 3 then the transaction is reverted! That is why I asked in the comment above - "Do you know how array indexing works?" (to which you responded sarcastically BTW).

Comment: @goodvibration Thank you, according to your comments I found a workaround for this. But man, you were sarcastic at first when you asked about how indexing works in solidity. I was seeking for an answer, not to be questioned.

Comment: I asked if you knew how indexing worked, because you seemed not to. In fact, your set of comments prior to that question of mine  ("length is 4" followed by "0, 1, 2, 3 working fine, 4 throws error") was a very solid proof of that. No workaround is needed here. Like I said, you should access `Players[_id][i].length` only for `i` between `0` and `Players[_id].length - 1` (in your example, between 0 and 3).